# Retrieving incoming gzip of photos - Rails Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gzip

Im trying to grab an incoming gzip file that will contain photos, i want to extract this gzip and for each photo upload this to s3. The uploading is not my issue, im unsure on how to properly parse the incoming gzip and get to the photos.

this is what i have so far in my controller.

```
raw_gzip_file = request.raw_post
photos = Zlib::GzipReader.open(gzip_file)
photos.each{|photo| s3.upload(photo)}
```

However im receiving errors ranging from (no implicit conversion of StringIO into String) and (string contains null byte)

Any help or suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a GzipReader with either the `open` method, which expects a file name or a the `new` method which expects an IO containing the data.

`raw_post` returns a string so you're passing the actual raw data to a method expecting a filename. You could wrap it in a StringIO and then then use `open` however there is already a method on `request` that will do that (or return the underlying input if it hasn't been read yet)

```
reader = Zlib::GzipReader.new(request.body)
```

This is only correct if the body really does just contain the gzip data. If, for example, the request is made by a browser submitting a form with a file input then the file data will be in `params` just like a normal form input (the raw post data would contain a multipart mime message which GzipReader wouldn't be able to handle)

Having done all that you'll run into the fact that Ruby's gzip library doesn't support multiple files in a single archive (see [issue](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/9790)). If you can get people to upload zip files (probably more consumer friendly) then the rubyzip gem can handle those

Comment: Thanks for the explanations, helped me understood it more. i'll look into using the rubyzip gem and using request.body instead of the raw_post method.